# How to get information from monitor serial to Linino?

Tags: mysql, json, arduino, monitor

I'm working in a project. And I need to pass information or catch from Monitor Serial and then send to Linino.

I want to convert information in a Json and send to PHP/MySQL.

Can I use "Bridge" sketch?

This is my sketch.

```
// ===================================================
//  ** PROYECTO SIMEE
// ===================================================

// -- variables and pins definition ------------------
const int analogInPin = A0;        // analog input pin 
int retardo = 2 ;    // (tiempo (s.) entre visionados)
float lectura,ff,pKW,iA,vV,vS,S_Ratio;

// -- initialize serial comm & parameters ------------
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600); 
S_Ratio = 36.5;      // Sensor/ratio (mV/mA ) : 36.5
vV = 230;            // valor de tension a computar
ff = 5; // freq. factor / (50Hz -> 5 / 60Hz -> 4.15)       
}

// -- smooth read routine ----------------------------
float smoothread(float fc){   // fc (factor corrector)
int ni = 35;          // n. de iteraciones => smooth
//  (ni) => rango 10 a 50 mejor promedio [smoothing]
float retorno = 0.0;
for (int x = 0; x< ni; x++){
do {                         // espero paso por cero  
  delayMicroseconds(100); 
  } while (analogRead(0) != 0) ;
  delay (ff);            // espera centro de ciclo
  delay (10);            // estabilizacion CAD
  retorno = retorno +(analogRead(0)*fc); 
}
return retorno / ni; 
}

// -- main loop --------------------------------------
void loop() { 
lectura = smoothread (1) / 1.41;    // lectura (rms)   
vS = (lectura * 0.0048);          // valor de C.A.D.
iA = (lectura * S_Ratio)/1000;     // Intensidad (A)
pKW = (vV * iA)/1000;               // Potencia (kW)

Serial.print("\n" );
Serial.print("\n================================" );
Serial.print("\n *** SIMEE ONLINE INC *** " );
Serial.print("\n================================\n" );
Serial.print("\n- Tension predefinida  [V] --> " );
Serial.print(vV,0);    
Serial.print("\n- Lectura del sensor   [V] --> " );
Serial.print(vS,3);    
Serial.print("\n- Intensidad calculada [A] --> " );
Serial.print(iA,3);  
Serial.print("\n- Potencia calculada  [kW] --> " );
Serial.print(pKW,3);  
Serial.print("\n-------------------------------\n" );
delay(retardo * 1000);                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are using the Arduino Yun? Yes, you'll need to use the Bridge library to communicate with the Linino.

I suggest writing your data to a file which Linino can then pick up and use to do something. Once done, it can delete the file and then wait for it to reappear.

I put together [a project you can find on Github](https://github.com/surfsoft/YunBuildMonitor) that demonstrates some of these things (although I write files in the Linino side and read them on the Arduino side).